# How to use firebase library without a VPN app in android

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, vpn

I made android app that uses firebase, but as the users live in Syria they should use a VPN to use my app because firebase is blocked in that country.

Is it possible to use a script or a JSON file in my app to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting up your own vpn connection inside the app you're developing.

[Try using this source to ease out your work.](https://github.com/hexene/LocalVPN)

another solution is that at runtime when your app attempts to connect with internet you can programatically reroute it's root default base connection route to your preferred IP address thus eventually solving your problem without using any external app.

Lastly,You can't try creating a service which will be installed in the backend and when the app is launched the service is automatically triggered with it and hence it will automatically route your connection to preferred vpn IP address.